# writing into csv file using poi.jar?

Tags: java

```
File f = new File(fileExportPath); //   D:/temp
    if(!f.exists())
    {
        f.mkdir();

    }
    f.setWritable(true);
    f.setExecutable(true);
String filePath = fileExportPath + File.separator;

         try {
             String Content="";
             Content+="\"Title\",\"Description\",\"DueDate\",\"AssignedTo\"\n";

             byte buf[] = Content.getBytes(); 
             OutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
             fileOut.write(buf);
             fileOut.close();
            }
```

OutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filePath); im getting error in this line

Comment: where can i give the filename, actuall i didnt specify the file name

Comment: ps. youre not even using poi in this code. i have also tried the code snippet and have no errors. perhaps there is a permissions problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "filePath" is a directory name.

```
String filePath = fileExportPath + File.separator;
```

It is necessary to add the file name to "filePath".

```
String filePath = fileExportPath + File.separator + "fileName";
```

Comment: how can i said default cell width in excel sheet using poi library and HSSF